# What does the word "that" mean?

Tags: meaning, word-meaning

> "Obviously the direct answer to the question is supposed to be, "I
>   wouldn't like it at all!" But what's the next step? Suppose you were
>   to say, "I wouldn't like it if someone did that to me. But luckily no
>   one is doing it to me. I’m doing it to someone else, and I don't mind
>   that at all!" This answer misses the point of the question. When you
>   are asked how you would like it if someone did that to you, you are
>   supposed to think about all the feelings you would have if someone
>   stole your umbrella. And **that** includes more than just "not liking
>   it"—**as** you wouldn't "like it" if you stubbed your toe on a rock. If
>   someone stole your umbrella you'd resent it."

[Thomas Nagel, What does it all mean?]

What do the words "that" and "as" mean?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The author is trying to make a distinction between dislike in the physical sense:

> You dislike it when you stub your toe.

and dislike in the emotional sense:

> You dislike it when someone steals your umbrella.

He wants to make clear what he means by the verb **like** in the phrase "not liking it".  But his language is not perfectly idiomatic.  The idiomatic way to indicate that you're offering an example to explain or clarify your intended meaning with a word or phrase you have just now used,  is with the phrase **as in**.

> And that includes more than just "not liking it"—**as in** you wouldn't "like
>   it" if you stubbed your toe on a rock.

as in {example phrase}.

I took her—as in "I *escorted* her" not "I *fleeced* her for all she was worth".

Answer (score 2):

Wow, the number of 'thats' in the paragraph...

So this use of "that" is as a pronoun, as to something previously mentioned. IN this instance, the word refers to the previous sentence of "things you are supposed to be thinking about".

> When you are asked how you would like it if someone did that to you, you are supposed to **think about all the feelings** you would have if someone stole your umbrella.

i.e. the object here is a collection of feelings, *that* includes more then 'just not liking it'.

As this is a set of instructions to someone, written in quite a conversational style, the 'as' is explaining that you must include more then just the "not liking it", because the "not liking it" is a general, generic feeling which can be expanded upon. In this instance, its the adverb meaning:

> adverb
>   1.
>   used in comparisons to refer to the extent or degree of something.